# dllexport a type with a std container of std::unique_ptr results in error C2280

Tags: c++, visual-c++, containers, unique-ptr, dllexport

I'm trying to `dllexport` a type with a *std container* of `std::unique_ptr` member, f.e.

```cpp
struct __declspec(dllexport) C {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> c_;
};
```

but whatever i try, msvc always complains about

```
msvc/14.33.31629/include\xutility(4145): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> &std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

The container type doesn't matter; the error is almost identical (always C2280) for vector, map, and others.

However, as soon as a `std::unique_ptr` member is added to the type, f.e.

```cpp
struct __declspec(dllexport) C {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> c_;
    std::unique_ptr<int> rup;
};
```

the error disappears.

I have no clue if this is the intended behavior, what causes this problem and how it can be fixed without adding a random `std::unique_ptr` member. What am i missing?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4bso9fK31)

Comment: The short answer really is: Don't. The C++ Standard Library makes no ABI stability guarantees. If you want to have a `std::unique_ptr` cross a DLL boundary, then both sides have to agree on the concrete implementation: Same compiler, same version. This is a hard requirement that's next to impossible to enforce. Only use types with well defined ABI layout at the interface, and even then you're [not entirely safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a member `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> c_;`, the compiler will provide a copy assignment operator `C& operator=(const C&)` that will try to copy the `c_` member. This will fail to compile if it is actually used, since the elements of `c_` can't be copied.

`__declspec(dllexport)` seems to try to create this implicitly-declared function (maybe to export it? Though it doesn't seem to actually do that), which fails.

When you add `std::unique_ptr<int> rup;`, this is a type without a copy constructor at all, so the implicit `operator=(const C&)` is suppressed (The move assign operator `C& operator=(C&&)` can still be used).

You can get rid of the implicit copy-assign operator by declaring a move-assign operator or a move constructor:

```cpp
struct __declspec(dllexport) C {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> c_;
    C(C&&) = default;
};
```

Or by inheriting from a move-only type/having a move-only member:

```cpp
struct move_only { constexpr move_only(move_only&&) noexcept = default; };

struct __declspec(dllexport) C : private move_only {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> c_;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`unique_ptr` is not a copyable type (or else it wouldn't be unique). The error message is complaining that something is trying to access the `unique_ptr`'s copy assignment operator, which has been disabled.

In your first example, your `C` struct has only copyable members, so a default copy constructor and copy assignment operator are generated for it by the compiler. Which then fails if they are invoked since `unique_ptr` can't be copied.

Whereas in your second example, your `C` struct has a non-copyable member, so the default copy constructor and copy assignment operator are not generated by the compiler.